# How to pass Serverside parameter in ASP.Core to React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I created a React/Typescript project with `dotnet new "ASP.NET Core with React.js"`.
index.cshtml:

```
<div id="react-app"></div>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main.js" asp-append-version="true">
    </script>
}
```

boot.tsx(shortened):

```
function renderApp() {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <BrowserRouter children={ routes } />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('react-app')
    );
}
renderApp();
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./routes', () => {
        routes = require<typeof RoutesModule>('./routes').routes;
        renderApp();
    });
}
```

How can I pass ASP.Core generated information(the routes from the controllers) to my react/typescript code?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the routes to the client? Usually you define your routes in your ClientApp, `routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute` forwards all relevant requests to your `routes.tsx` file.

Comment: @Stephan Because I thought it would be a good idea to generate the API backend Routes on the server. e.g. via `Url.Action("Home", "GetTemperatures")` To reduce duplication. I would be super grateful for suggestions/tips on other ways to do it.

Comment: In my opinion there is nothing wrong with hardcoding the API paths. For example the template simply calls `fetch('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')`(https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/dev/templates/ReactSpa/ClientApp/components/FetchData.tsx#L15); you maybe could separate the constant endpoint address (`/api/`) and the request path (`SampleData/WeatherForecasts`). Dynamically loading the paths from your server is for most use cases much more overhead than simplification.

Comment: Thanks, I will hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

To use server-side rendering in your application, follow the following steps:

1 - Modify App_Start\ReactConfig.cs (for ASP.NET MVC 4 or 5) or Startup.cs (for ASP.NET Core) to reference your components:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public static class ReactConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration = new ReactSiteConfiguration()
                .AddScript("~/Scripts/HelloWorld.jsx");
        }
    }
}
```

This tells ReactJS.NET to load all the relevant JavaScript files server-side. The JavaScript files of all the components you want to load and all their dependencies should be included here.

2 - In your ASP.NET MVC view, call Html.React to render a component server-side, passing it the name of the component, and any required props.

```
@Html.React("HelloWorld", new
{
    name = "Daniel"
})
```

3 - Call Html.ReactInitJavaScript at the bottom of the page (just above the ) to render initialisation scripts. Note that this does not load the JavaScript files for your components, it only renders the initialisation code.

```
<!-- Load all your scripts normally before calling ReactInitJavaScript -->
<!-- Assumes minification/combination is configured as per previous section -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
```

4 - Hit the page and admire the server-rendered beauty:

```
<div id="react1">
    <div data-reactid=".2aubxk2hwsu" data-react-checksum="-1025167618">
        <span data-reactid=".2aubxk2hwsu.0">Hello </span>
        <span data-reactid=".2aubxk2hwsu.1">Daniel</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/HelloWorld.js"></script>
<script>ReactDOM.render(HelloWorld({"name":"Daniel"}), document.getElementById("react1"));</script>
```

The server-rendered HTML will automatically be reused by React client-side, meaning your initial render will be super fast.

If you encounter any errors with the JavaScript, you may want to temporarily disable server-side rendering in order to debug your components in your browser. You can do this by calling DisableServerSideRendering() in your ReactJS.NET config.

For a more in-depth example, take a look at the included sample application (React.Samples.Mvc4).

5 - Server-side only rendering

If there is no need to have a React application client side and you just want to use the server side rendering but without the React specific data attributes, call Html.React and pass serverOnly parameter as true.

```
@Html.React("HelloWorld", new
{
    name = "Daniel"
}, serverOnly: true)
```

And the HTML will look like the one following which is a lot cleaner. In this case there is no need to load the React script or call the Html.ReactInitJavaScript() method.

```
<div id="react1">
    <div>
        <span>Hello </span>
        <span>Daniel</span>
    </div>
</div>
```